# how should I implement an angular select directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive

I am trying to implement my own select element using angular directive and facing a dilemma where to build the object being passed to the select directive upon the directive will build the markup for the select.

As controller is described in the angular documentation it says that controller should have nothing to do with UI code in it so it brings me to write the object inside the html template:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <my-select items="[{name:'name1', value:'value1'},...,{name:'name(n)', value:'value(n)}]></my-select>
</div>
```

But looking at the result is somehow feels much better to write it inside the controller.js file:

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.selectItems=[{name:'name1', value:'value1'},...,{name:'name(n)', value:'value(n)}];
}
```

and in the markup to write something like this:

```
<my-select items="selectItems"...></my-select>
```

What is the "Angular Way" than to do it?

Thanks,

Eran

Comment: "As controller is described in the angular documentation it says that directive should have nothing to do with UI code". This is wrong. The controller should have nothing to do with UI code, but the directive should have everything to do with UI code.

Comment: @jonas Thanks for the correction, you right I meant controller but wrote directive, fixed it.

Comment: @IlanFrumer I thought directives are actually the least testable constructs in angular?

Comment: I wouldn't use your directives in production with that attitude.
The only reason they are hard to test is because they make dom manipulation and use jquery plugins ext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Maybe inside a view(template)?

Most select options are part of the model not of the view and so they should be delivered via controllers.
The only exception is ui specific data that is not dynamic that for practical reasons can be hard-coded to the template.

but even so, the template should never be cluttered with huge data objects, It's not worth it.

#### Maybe inside a directive?

Directives should be implemented as a reusable and testable components so it's a big mistake to just put application specific data inside them.

#### quick prototyping?

For quick prototyping and very small objects you can probably go each way.

#### Conclusion

If you had 1000 options , would you still consider hard coding them inside your views or directives?

Go with controllers. probably much of your real application data should be saved on a real server anyway.

Comment: Thanks @ilan, I believe that if I had 1000 options it would have come from a service. In the code example I am setting the selectItems object not in the directive controller but in the parent controller which holds the directive, just like that it written in the markup on the view that holds/defines the directive

Comment: A directive controller is the same as a directive. It should be all part of a reusable component/s.
A controller(the one with ng-contoller or ngRoute: controller) is the way to go.

Comment: You can always create those objects as services (service/factory/value/provider) and put them on the scope.

Comment: In case you dont know, you can use scope isolates to perform efficient data binding from inside a directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/T7Exv2MvRkdVglPNksvY?p=preview